# Declaring a function var vs declaring on the scope in an angularjs Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Am I correct in saying that it is better to declare a function on the scope, rather than declare a function reference, because of memory management?

The scope is automatically cleaned up after use by the garbage collector, whereas function references may hang around as unused clutter?

So, instead of this:

```
function updateMaxHeight() { }
```

do this:

```
scope._updateMaxHeight = function() { }
```

By the way, as an aside, I've declared the function using underscore to mark it as private.

Comment: _"The scope is automatically cleaned up after use by the garbage collector, whereas function references may hang around as unused clutter?"_ Did you read this somewhere? The garbage collector should clean up anything that no longer has any references. _"By the way, as an aside, I've declared the function using underscore to mark it as private."_ This will have no effect whasoever on the way the JavaScript engine treats the function, if that's what you're implying.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That's what I want to know. Does angularjs take care of managing objects on the scope so that you don't have to set them to null or undefined to manage memory leaks?

Comment: Thanks. The underscore is more a readability thing for developers. My understanding is that there is no such thing as private in javascript.

Comment: You should basically declare functions on the scope if they are to be called from the view. Otherwise, don't place them on the view.